# MATLAB error: “Matrix dimensions must agree” when not dealing with matrices

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the displacement x(t) as shown but i keep on getting the error

```
Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

My code is as shown below and its for an over damped vibration system

```
for i = 1 : 100; 
   t(i)= i/40;
   x(i) = (C1*exp(-s+(((s^2)-1)^.5)*Wn*t)) + (C2*exp(-s-(((s^2)-1)^.5)*Wn*t));
end
```

I looked up this problem earlier and I saw a similar problem where a (.) was missing in front of the operator and tried this on my code but still couldn't get it to work. I don't know if I placed them in the wrong places or not but I am still stuck.

Could anyone please show me where I went wrong?

Comment: it's basic MATRIX math, you have got both sizes incompatible. MATLAB is smart, but not too much of a smart thing to understand your mind all the time. Check what your C1 and C2 are and debug through the line where you are assigning x(i)Also, try and use this `x(i) = (C1.*exp(-s+(((s^2)-1)^.5)*Wn*t))+ (C2.*exp(-s-(((s^2)-1)^.5)*Wn*t))` Assuming your Wn and t are both 1-D vectors. At least update the question clarifying the size for Wn

Comment: As hagubear commented, for matlab * is a Matrix mulltiplication. So if you have vectors and you want to apply elementwise multiploation, you need to use .*

Answer (score 4):

This is very likely because you use `t` inside the expression for `x`, and not `t(i)`. (Assuming all other variables are scalars.

Try:

```
for ii = 1 : 100; 
   t(ii)= ii/40
   x(ii) = (C1*exp(-s+(((s^2)-1)^0.5)*Wn*t(ii)))+ (C2*exp(-s-(((s^2)-1)^0.5)*Wn*t(ii)))
end
```

A better solution would be to vectorize this:

```
t = (1:100)./40;
x = (C1.*exp(-s+(((s^2)-1)^.5)*Wn.*t))+ (C2.*exp(-s-(((s^2)-1)^.5)*Wn.*t))
```